# Postgres: Using function variable names in pgsql function

Tags: postgresql, function

I have written a pgsql function along the lines of what's shown below. How can I get rid of the $1, $2, etc. and replace them with the real argument names to make the function code more readable?

Regards

Peter

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION InsertUser (
    UserID UUID,
    FirstName CHAR(10),
    Surname VARCHAR(75),
    Email VARCHAR(75)
)
RETURNS void
AS
$$
INSERT INTO "User" (userid,firstname,surname,email)
VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this thing

```
    CREATE or replace FUNCTION delhi(nam varchar, mm numeric , nn numeric  ) RETURNS integer
    AS $$
        begin
        insert into exe ( name , m1 ,m2 )  values ( nam, mm , nn );
-- see here column name is not like function argument name , so that it wont say error
           return 1;
    end ;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Function calling :

```
select delhi ( 'first value', 2,3 ) ;
```

Comment: ok that seems to work. But not sure why?? All I see that's materially different is that you excluded the explicit column names in the insert statement. Can one not use explicit column names?

Comment: and how come it works for you not enclosing the table name in quotes "? When I try Insert into user PGAdmin complains. I need to say Insert into "User"

Comment: See, you can give the column name explicit , But that should not be 
function argument name . If you have function argument name as column name . that is interpret as $1, $2 .

Comment: Peter, the keyword "User" is reserved in Postgres, as a result you must double quote it to use it as a table.

Answer (score 5):

You must declare it before you use it at the declare area. For exemple :

```
DECLARE   
    v_UserID alias for $1;
    v_FirstName alias for $2;
    v_Surname alias for $3;
    v_Email alias for $4;
BEGIN
$$
END
```